# PHP Login Page Redirect

Tags: php, authentication, href

this code is incomplete and I need it to redirect to a page called mainpage.php with hardcoded information for the username and password. Here's the code.

```
<?php
session_start();
$username="user";
$password="123";

if($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password)
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style='text-align:center'>
        <h3>Welcome To Kontak</h3>
        </div>
        <hr /><br />
        <form id='login' action="" method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
            <fieldset style="width:550px">
            <legend>Admin Login</legend>
            <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

            <label for='username' >UserName:</label>
            <input type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50" />


            <label for='password' >Password:</label>
            <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />

            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what exactly you want to do? whatever you said it's not enough..

Answer (score 5):

I think you are looking for this:

```
if($_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password)

header( 'Location: mainpage.php' );
?>
```

so the header will take to mainpage.php when if condition is satisfied.
--Vijay

Comment: PHP has a verify_pasword function or string compare . Its more efficient that using the above                    http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php

Comment: how to pass parameters by post param ?

Answer (score 1):

Have to start and end the if block

```
<?php
session_start();
$username="user";
$password="123";

if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'] == $username && $_POST['password'] == $password)
{
    header("Location: your_page.php");
}
else
{
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style='text-align:center'>
        <h3>Welcome To Kontak</h3>
        </div>
        <hr /><br />
        <form id='login' action="" method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
            <fieldset style="width:550px">
            <legend>Admin Login</legend>
            <input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>

            <label for='username' >UserName:</label>
            <input type='text' name='username' id='username'  maxlength="50" />


            <label for='password' >Password:</label>
            <input type='password' name='password' id='password' maxlength="50" />

            <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: yup copied that statement to avoid typing again the same but that was added in my edited copy of this answer

Comment: I tried out the code and it works, but now it leaves me with an undefined index: username

Comment: sorry change  isset($_POST) to  isset($_POST['username'])

Answer (score 0):

Change 'header("Location: your_page.php");' to 'header("Location: mainpage.php");'