# Redirect to different assigned pages if username and password correct

Tags: php, redirect, http-redirect

Please I need help regarding a `PHP` error, I want to redirect to different pages with form login input here since I do not how to know how to make an admin backend to redirect users to different pages via database, Here is my `PHP`

SCRIPT

// Redirect to different page

```
<?php $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $userpass = $_POST['password']; 

    if (strcmp($userid, "3495062250") && strcmp($password, "12smith00") ) { 
    header('location: account-dashboard/client_349506_2243/index.html');

   } else{ header('location: error.html'); } ?>
```

Comment: <?php
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $userpass = $_POST['password'];

    if (strcmp($userid, "3495062250") && strcmp($password, "12smith00") )
    {
        header('location: account-dashboard/client_349506_2243/index.html');
    }
 else{ header('location: error.html');
 }
?>

Comment: Please add the code inside your question not in comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Login Page Redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782194/php-login-page-redirect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check below code.

You did mistakes.

- In if condition you have used `$password` instead of `$userpass`
- You can simply compare the string using `equal operator` in `PHP`

  ```
  $userid = $_POST['userid'];
  $userpass = $_POST['password'];
  if ($userid = "3495062250" && $userpass == "12smith00") {
      header('location: account-dashboard/client_349506_2243/index.html');
  } else {
      header('location: error.html');
  }
  ```